# File removed before we read it

Tags: tar

I'm making a tarball of a directory with `tar -C "$DIR" -chf "$TARBALL"` and a few files keep giving me the warning, "File removed before we read it". The files are there, and I'm not running any other processes at the same time that could be writing over the files.
What does this error mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of the `-h` flag, tar needs to follow any symbolic links it finds. Any broken symbolic link will give the error "File removed before we read it" e.g. symbolic links that no longer lead to valid files. 
Either:

- make sure all the links point to valid files
- remove all the invalid links
- remove the `-h` flag, to shallow copy the links (rather than the files they point to)